# Construct and debug a PL/SQL simple or complex select view statement in a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, toad

How do I perform a select on a rather simple view in oracle pl/sql using a stored procedure.

Lets say the view looks like this:

```
FirstName   LastName
--------    -------
Bob         Jones
James       Kay
etc...
```

To me its should be so simple:

```
Procedure SuperSimple()
begin
  select FirstName, LastName from SuperSimple
end
```

However I've been told that this will not work.

So I tried to use a PL/SQL cursor.  Still scratching my head trying to figure out why I am using cursors.  But it appears to be necessary in 11g.

```
Procedure AlphaPrime(Results OUT Ref CURSOR) IS
begin
OPEN Results for 
  select FirstName, LastName from SuperSimple;
end;
```

Now I was hoping this would work but I'm doing something like this with select statements and it appears to be not working.

Do I also need to add a fetch and another open and a close command to make this thing work?  What is the idea behind all this?  I've noticed that trying to find info on how to add a very simple select statemetn to a procedure appears to be missing from most documentation that I've read.  Is there a reason for this like its too simple to add a select statement to a procedure as it would be better to add it to a view.  Something along those lines.

The problem I'm having is I want to start out really simple and tac on a little bit more complexity to the sproc over time... where time ~ 1  to 2 hours.  Can someone point me to some docs in Oracle PL/SQL that shows how to add a simple table or view.  Also If the permissions for a specific view or table is not allowed does it just fail for that user or does it give an empty result set.

Comment: Yeah, which one of those had a simple query?

Comment: Also I'm getting an error sayin gPLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement even when adding an "as" before the select statement.

Comment: Finally if I tack on a join does that convert it from an explicit query to an implicit query?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? That isn't entirely a rhetorical question, it isn't clear what you're trying to achieve, so which solution is suitable. Why do you want to select from a procedure at all instead of directly from the view? If you're hiding complexity, that's what views are for, generally. How will you consume the output - do you want to retrieve a ref cursor you can then iterate over in PL/SQL or an application, or do you want to be able to call this from a plain SQL query (which comes back to... why).

Comment: First of all I'm fairly inexperienced with Oracle.  This is why this question if posed in another language, I'm finding, is much different than in the Oracle PL/SQL environment.  I'm actually moving toward using Collections and learning about VArray architecture right now to solve my problem.  See I have bunch of unions of a view in separate schemas that when complete for all can be greater that 32000 characters.  So I want to loop through each table/view instead and call a view or a procedure and put the results in a collection.  Right now I'm still debating on how to form the index.

Comment: Also the above actually worked for me, but I just realized in debug mode in toad that it says I have insuffiecient priviledges.  I didn't realize that I could just ignore that.  I don't understand why the Toad idea for Oracle PL/SQL gave me that error except that maybe the view I was trying to debug access parts that are read only if you look at the entire view structure.  However, I wasn't doing a write, just accessing it through a procedure.

Comment: The source for the view would be more than 32k? Crikey. That doesn't necessarily mean a lot of results, but bear in mind that collections can use up a lot of valuable memory. You should perhaps look at a pipelined function instead if you're set on a PL/SQL solution. Depends on how the final result set will be used maybe.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your question what are you intending to do with the query result inside your procedure. So here I make some examples with dbms_output which prints to screen out some message and data from your query. Probably you will replace it with your logic.

Let's have some view (actually it doesn't matter here whether you are querying view or table, but I would stick to your question)

```
 create table some_simple_table(firstname varchar2(30), lastname   varchar2(30));
 / 
   create or replace view supersimple_view as select firstname, lastname,    'whatever1' whatever from some_simple_table;
 /
```

The following code does select into variable, this will work only if query returns **exactly one row**.

```
 create or replace procedure supersimple1 is
    vfirstname supersimple_view.firstname%type;
    vwhatever supersimple_view.whatever%type;
    vsupersimple supersimple_view%rowtype;
 begin
    select firstname, whatever into vfirstname, vwhatever from    supersimple_view;  
    dbms_output.put_line('I''m doing some logic with this'|| vwhatever );
    select * into vsupersimple from supersimple_view;
    dbms_output.put_line('I''m doing some logic with this'||   vsupersimple.firstname);
end;
    /
```

Perhaps you can implement implicit cursor loop through results and do some logic.

```
create or replace procedure supersimple2 is
 begin
  for rec in (select * from supersimple_view)
  loop
      dbms_output.put_line('I''m doing some logic with this record '||   rec.firstname);
  end loop;
  end;
 /
```

Another option is cursor (particularly in case when you will reuse the same select) loop through results and do some logic.

```
 create or replace procedure supersimple3 is
  cursor cur is (select * from supersimple_view);
    vsupersimple cur%rowtype;
 begin
 open cur ;
  loop
    FETCH cur INTO vsupersimple;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND; 
    dbms_output.put_line('I''m doing some logic with this record '|| vsupersimple.firstname);
  end loop;
 close cur;
end;
```

/

You can fetch result of your query to collection

```
create or replace procedure supersimple4 is
type supersimple_colt is table of supersimple_view%rowtype index by    pls_integer;
vsupersimple_col supersimple_colt; 
begin
  select * bulk collect into vsupersimple_col from supersimple_view ;
  for i in 1 .. vsupersimple_col.count
  loop
           dbms_output.put_line('I''m doing some logic with this record '||  vsupersimple_col(i).firstname);
  end loop;
 end;
/
```

Instead of PL/SQL type declared in supersimple4 you can create standalone database SQL types and used them to fetch results into. This aproach gives you various features like: possibility to query collection in select statement in table like fashion, converting it to xml by xmltype, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.  For each column that is selected on, it needs a view or table column type, which is sort of like the list of parameters used for the final output.  That way when you declare on it you can better know what you are getting, which sorta makes sense.

So if you have two tables or views which were used to generate the output columns, you would need both of those tables or views in your descriptive OUT variables to describe better what you are outputting in the final output result.

See this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-stored-procedure-select-into-example/).

I'm taking an educated guess with this next part as I'm just beginning to understand it:

This query should work.  But if its not it may be due to insuffiecient priviledges.  Try a table that you know you have access and select it in a procedure in debug mode.  Then try a view.

```
Procedure AlphaPrime(Results OUT Ref CURSOR) IS
begin
OPEN Results for 
  select FirstName, LastName from SuperSimple;
end;
```

Also there is a possibility with Debug mode and your assigned user roles that you may have insufficient priviledges to debug all the objects in the view and they may not be accessible.  Sometimes you can just hit the "Ignore" button in Toad to skip over debugging inside a stored procedure.  Also you may have priveledges to view the results the object just not view its structure which may also give you insufficient priviledges errors.  Again just ignore them to skip over those types of issues and see the results while in debug mode.  If you don't debug this, then you should not see any errors and just get the results.

Comment: That's to retrieve multiple scalar values; but a single value for each argument. That doesn't seem to be what your original procedure is trying to do - you want the values from all rows, not from a single row. A select ... into will error if you try to get more than one row.